# ElasticSearch: Installing ES plugin in Windows 64-bit environment

Tags: windows, plugins, elasticsearch

what are the specific steps to install an ES plugin like like Elasticsearch-head and Inquistor on a Windows 64-bit environment?

I have downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor
then unzipped it and put it in the plugins directory of my ES folder but 
going to

```
      http://localhost:9200/_plugin/inquisitor/ returns a blank page in my browser.
```

Answer (score 0):

- Unzip file "elasticsearch-inquisitor-master.zip"
- Inside there is a folder named "_site". Copy-paste it inside "ElasticSearch\plugins\inquisitor\"
- You must have this structure: "ElasticSearch\plugins\inquisitor\_site"
- Browse: `http://localhost:9200/_plugin/inquisitor/`

Comment: Can you please tell me why I am getting error "property [elasticsearch.version] is missing for plugin [elasticsearch-inquisitor]"

Comment: Please check https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration/issues/107 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411822/elasticsearch-version-is-missing-for-plugin-elasticsearch-inquisitor-error-u