# elasticsearch.version is missing for plugin [elasticsearch-inquisitor], ERROR: Unknown plugin polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins

I am Installing plugin `elasticsearch-inquisitor` in Elasticsearch on my Windows, but I am getting error.

> [elasticsearch.version] is missing for plugin
>   [elasticsearch-inquisitor]

and on Linux I am getting error

> ERROR: Unknown plugin polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor

Can anyone please tell me how can I install this plugin.

Comment: Normally, it's a version compatibility issue between elasticSearch and its plugin(s).

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is `version` element in file `plugin-descriptor.properties` ,which locate  at `/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/{plugin}/`  usually.

The format for this file is described in detail here 
[/buildSrc/src/main/resources/plugin-descriptor.properties](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/resources/plugin-descriptor.properties)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you forgot to prefix `file:///` to the path of your local plugin. See also https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugin-management-custom-url.html.

(That's just a guess because you didn't show what exactly you've done.)